Python - Have two datasets which are measuring the same thing, how can I fit them together?
I have two datasets, both measures of sea level at a particular location. Although these are both measuring sea level, they are measured with different devices and different methods, and thus have different values and scales at many points.
I know for sure that one dataset is more accurate than the other, and thus I want to fit the second dataset to the first as closely as possible, and then find a way to measure agreement.
The datasets also do not have the same lengths, and for each x value, there is not always a y value for both (e.g. on a certain day and hour, one dataset has a point, but the other may not)
I tried matching the distance between their minimum and maximum points and then shifting in order to match the mean of each, but this isn't ideal as there are some outliers which make the fit imperfect.
Image below shows what I've gotten to
This is what I currently have, based on trial and error:

Edit: I have defined a variable which is just the difference between each point of the two datasets. I'd like to minimize this variable. Not sure how I would go about doing this part.
Datasets are below:
# reference data set - this is correct data
# year, month, day, hour, height
2024,4,30,0,2218
2024,4,30,1,2230
2024,4,30,2,2254
2024,4,30,3,2333
2024,4,30,4,2429
2024,4,30,5,2539
2024,4,30,6,2652
2024,4,30,7,2738
2024,4,30,8,2783
2024,4,30,9,2756
2024,4,30,10,2640
2024,4,30,11,2449
2024,4,30,12,2200
2024,4,30,13,1933
2024,4,30,14,1659
2024,4,30,15,1464
2024,4,30,16,1357
2024,4,30,17,1332
2024,4,30,18,1428
2024,4,30,19,1557
2024,4,30,20,1743
2024,4,30,21,1950
2024,4,30,22,2120
2024,4,30,23,2235
2024,5,1,0,-32767
2024,5,1,1,2310
2024,5,1,2,2294
2024,5,1,3,2274
2024,5,1,4,2270
2024,5,1,5,2319
2024,5,1,6,2386
2024,5,1,7,2477
2024,5,1,8,2575
2024,5,1,9,2651
2024,5,1,10,2684
2024,5,1,11,2625
2024,5,1,12,2472
2024,5,1,13,2260
2024,5,1,14,1993
2024,5,1,15,1720
2024,5,1,16,1506
2024,5,1,17,1368
2024,5,1,18,1309
2024,5,1,19,1374
2024,5,1,20,1546
2024,5,1,21,1786
2024,5,1,22,2041
2024,5,1,23,2241
2024,5,2,0,2390
2024,5,2,1,2454
2024,5,2,2,2437
2024,5,2,3,2363
2024,5,2,4,2289
2024,5,2,5,2216
2024,5,2,6,2194
2024,5,2,7,2231
2024,5,2,8,2325
2024,5,2,9,2477
2024,5,2,10,2602
2024,5,2,11,2671
2024,5,2,12,2664
2024,5,2,13,2545
2024,5,2,14,2314
2024,5,2,15,2041
2024,5,2,16,1747
2024,5,2,17,1481
2024,5,2,18,1326
2024,5,2,19,1278
2024,5,2,20,1375
2024,5,2,21,1590
2024,5,2,22,1898
2024,5,2,23,2191
2024,5,3,0,2433
2024,5,3,1,2572
2024,5,3,2,2596
2024,5,3,3,2508
2024,5,3,4,2347
2024,5,3,5,2171
2024,5,3,6,2015
2024,5,3,7,1950
2024,5,3,8,1992
2024,5,3,9,2136
2024,5,3,10,2333
2024,5,3,11,2533
2024,5,3,12,2675
2024,5,3,13,2718
2024,5,3,14,2605
2024,5,3,15,2397
2024,5,3,16,2104
2024,5,3,17,1769
2024,5,3,18,1486
2024,5,3,19,1330
2024,5,3,20,1303
2024,5,3,21,1488
2024,5,3,22,1782
2024,5,3,23,2109
2024,5,4,0,2449
2024,5,4,1,2696
2024,5,4,2,2802
2024,5,4,3,2735
2024,5,4,4,2544
2024,5,4,5,2285
2024,5,4,6,1993
2024,5,4,7,1799
2024,5,4,8,1704
2024,5,4,9,1763
2024,5,4,10,1976
2024,5,4,11,2245
2024,5,4,12,2506
2024,5,4,13,2705
2024,5,4,14,2761
2024,5,4,15,2655
2024,5,4,16,2399
2024,5,4,17,2059
2024,5,4,18,1714
2024,5,4,19,1453
2024,5,4,20,1341
2024,5,4,21,1405
2024,5,4,22,1654
2024,5,4,23,2023
2024,5,5,0,2413
2024,5,5,1,2745
2024,5,5,2,2953
2024,5,5,3,2968
2024,5,5,4,2782
2024,5,5,5,2467
2024,5,5,6,2080
2024,5,5,7,1726
2024,5,5,8,1498
2024,5,5,9,1441
2024,5,5,10,1557
2024,5,5,11,1832
2024,5,5,12,2171
2024,5,5,13,2499
2024,5,5,14,2710
2024,5,5,15,2752
2024,5,5,16,2633
2024,5,5,17,2335
2024,5,5,18,1991
2024,5,5,19,1663
2024,5,5,20,1445
2024,5,5,21,1416
2024,5,5,22,1565
2024,5,5,23,1900
2024,5,6,0,2321
2024,5,6,1,2727
2024,5,6,2,3040
2024,5,6,3,3147
2024,5,6,4,3030
2024,5,6,5,2723
2024,5,6,6,2271
2024,5,6,7,1811
2024,5,6,8,1438
2024,5,6,9,1213
2024,5,6,10,1192
2024,5,6,11,1377
2024,5,6,12,1699
2024,5,6,13,2083
2024,5,6,14,2417
2024,5,6,15,2634
2024,5,6,16,2682
2024,5,6,17,2531
2024,5,6,18,2259
2024,5,6,19,1942
2024,5,6,20,1663
2024,5,6,21,1534
2024,5,6,22,1592
2024,5,6,23,1809
2024,5,7,0,2179
2024,5,7,1,2618
2024,5,7,2,3005
2024,5,7,3,3226
2024,5,7,4,3238
2024,5,7,5,3039
2024,5,7,6,2617
2024,5,7,7,2113
2024,5,7,8,1626
2024,5,7,9,1254
2024,5,7,10,1061
2024,5,7,11,1106
2024,5,7,12,1322
2024,5,7,13,1690
2024,5,7,14,2078
2024,5,7,15,2414
2024,5,7,16,2597
2024,5,7,17,2595
2024,5,7,18,2437
2024,5,7,19,2185
2024,5,7,20,1918
2024,5,7,21,1735
2024,5,7,22,1680
2024,5,7,23,1808
2024,5,8,0,2093
2024,5,8,1,2490
2024,5,8,2,2913
2024,5,8,3,3231
2024,5,8,4,3357
2024,5,8,5,3277
2024,5,8,6,2966
2024,5,8,7,2491
2024,5,8,8,1956
2024,5,8,9,1453
2024,5,8,10,1124
2024,5,8,11,987
2024,5,8,12,1055
2024,5,8,13,1315
2024,5,8,14,1672
2024,5,8,15,2051
2024,5,8,16,2360
2024,5,8,17,2524
2024,5,8,18,2518
2024,5,8,19,2389
2024,5,8,20,2164
2024,5,8,21,1962
2024,5,8,22,1863
2024,5,8,23,1856
2024,5,9,0,2045
2024,5,9,1,2358
2024,5,9,2,2722
2024,5,9,3,3081
2024,5,9,4,3307
2024,5,9,5,3347
2024,5,9,6,3181
2024,5,9,7,2810
2024,5,9,8,2323
2024,5,9,9,1806
2024,5,9,10,-32767
2024,5,9,11,1078
2024,5,9,12,961
2024,5,9,13,1056
2024,5,9,14,1311
2024,5,9,15,1670
2024,5,9,16,2011
2024,5,9,17,2264
2024,5,9,18,2415
2024,5,9,19,2420
2024,5,9,20,2302
2024,5,9,21,2128
2024,5,9,22,1992
2024,5,9,23,1934
2024,5,10,0,2000
2024,5,10,1,2201
2024,5,10,2,2512
2024,5,10,3,2854
2024,5,10,4,3113
2024,5,10,5,3275
2024,5,10,6,3228
2024,5,10,7,3012
2024,5,10,8,2644
2024,5,10,9,2170
2024,5,10,10,1686
2024,5,10,11,1306
2024,5,10,12,1060
2024,5,10,13,1007
2024,5,10,14,1110
2024,5,10,15,1377
2024,5,10,16,1688
2024,5,10,17,1976
2024,5,10,18,2202
2024,5,10,19,2319
2024,5,10,20,2323
2024,5,10,21,2251
2024,5,10,22,2133
2024,5,10,23,2059
2024,5,11,0,2048
2024,5,11,1,2138
2024,5,11,2,2342
2024,5,11,3,2604
2024,5,11,4,2860
2024,5,11,5,3069
2024,5,11,6,3126
2024,5,11,7,3051
2024,5,11,8,2839
2024,5,11,9,2492
2024,5,11,10,2056
2024,5,11,11,1656
2024,5,11,12,1326
2024,5,11,13,1147
2024,5,11,14,1102
2024,5,11,15,1218
2024,5,11,16,1447
2024,5,11,17,1710
2024,5,11,18,1961
2024,5,11,19,2157
2024,5,11,20,2263
2024,5,11,21,2289
2024,5,11,22,2258
2024,5,11,23,2178
2024,5,12,0,2136
2024,5,12,1,2153
2024,5,12,2,2257
2024,5,12,3,2424
2024,5,12,4,2636
2024,5,12,5,2835
2024,5,12,6,2965
2024,5,12,7,2982
2024,5,12,8,2889
2024,5,12,9,2674
2024,5,12,10,2356
2024,5,12,11,2026
2024,5,12,12,1691
2024,5,12,13,1432
2024,5,12,14,1274
2024,5,12,15,1254
2024,5,12,16,1362
2024,5,12,17,1552
2024,5,12,18,1759
2024,5,12,19,1962
2024,5,12,20,2157
2024,5,12,21,2270
2024,5,12,22,2315
2024,5,12,23,2306
2024,5,13,0,2263
2024,5,13,1,2241
2024,5,13,2,2254
2024,5,13,3,2333
2024,5,13,4,2453
2024,5,13,5,2587
2024,5,13,6,2714
2024,5,13,7,2795
2024,5,13,8,2801
2024,5,13,9,2718
2024,5,13,10,2533
2024,5,13,11,2290
2024,5,13,12,2004
2024,5,13,13,1713
2024,5,13,14,1503
2024,5,13,15,1361
2024,5,13,16,1343
2024,5,13,17,1408
2024,5,13,18,1564
2024,5,13,19,1754
2024,5,13,20,1955
2024,5,13,21,2137
2024,5,13,22,2274
2024,5,13,23,2333
2024,5,14,0,2344
2024,5,14,1,2316
2024,5,14,2,2297
2024,5,14,3,2291
2024,5,14,4,2326
2024,5,14,5,2396
2024,5,14,6,2473
2024,5,14,7,2572
2024,5,14,8,2635
2024,5,14,9,2643
2024,5,14,10,2590
2024,5,14,11,2468
2024,5,14,12,2265
2024,5,14,13,2033
2024,5,14,14,1814
2024,5,14,15,1615
2024,5,14,16,1495
2024,5,14,17,1465
2024,5,14,18,1500
2024,5,14,19,1651
2024,5,14,20,1836
2024,5,14,21,2032
2024,5,14,22,2228
2024,5,14,23,2356
2024,5,15,0,2420
2024,5,15,1,2424
2024,5,15,2,2405
2024,5,15,3,2356
2024,5,15,4,2306
2024,5,15,5,2288
2024,5,15,6,2304
2024,5,15,7,2349
2024,5,15,8,2420
2024,5,15,9,2486
2024,5,15,10,2526
2024,5,15,11,2509
2024,5,15,12,2419
2024,5,15,13,2267
2024,5,15,14,2046
2024,5,15,15,1836
2024,5,15,16,1657
2024,5,15,17,1536
2024,5,15,18,1505
2024,5,15,19,1556
2024,5,15,20,1710
2024,5,15,21,1912
2024,5,15,22,2123
2024,5,15,23,2325
2024,5,16,0,2468
2024,5,16,1,2503
2024,5,16,2,2494
2024,5,16,3,2427
2024,5,16,4,2332
2024,5,16,5,2226
2024,5,16,6,2175
2024,5,16,7,2164
2024,5,16,8,2190
2024,5,16,9,2267
2024,5,16,10,2356
2024,5,16,11,2433
2024,5,16,12,2463
2024,5,16,13,2412
2024,5,16,14,2267
2024,5,16,15,2074
2024,5,16,16,1841
2024,5,16,17,1680
2024,5,16,18,1570
2024,5,16,19,1547
2024,5,16,20,1632
2024,5,16,21,1808
2024,5,16,22,2043
2024,5,16,23,2266
2024,5,17,0,2463
2024,5,17,1,2562
2024,5,17,2,2573
2024,5,17,3,2492
2024,5,17,4,2343
2024,5,17,5,2189
2024,5,17,6,2032
2024,5,17,7,1929
2024,5,17,8,1912
2024,5,17,9,1990
2024,5,17,10,2104
2024,5,17,11,2263
2024,5,17,12,2368
2024,5,17,13,2409
2024,5,17,14,2360
2024,5,17,15,2235
2024,5,17,16,2038
2024,5,17,17,1821
2024,5,17,18,1661
2024,5,17,19,1588
2024,5,17,20,1599
2024,5,17,21,1737
2024,5,17,22,1959
2024,5,17,23,2224
2024,5,18,0,2463
2024,5,18,1,2618
2024,5,18,2,2681
2024,5,18,3,2624
2024,5,18,4,2468
2024,5,18,5,2247
2024,5,18,6,2033
2024,5,18,7,1860
2024,5,18,8,1778
2024,5,18,9,1796
2024,5,18,10,1900
2024,5,18,11,2076
2024,5,18,12,2250
2024,5,18,13,2378
2024,5,18,14,2407
2024,5,18,15,2346
2024,5,18,16,2192
2024,5,18,17,1959
2024,5,18,18,1771
2024,5,18,19,1640
2024,5,18,20,1601
2024,5,18,21,1699
2024,5,18,22,1896
2024,5,18,23,2152
2024,5,19,0,2440
2024,5,19,1,2650
2024,5,19,2,2766
2024,5,19,3,2730
2024,5,19,4,2583
2024,5,19,5,2334
2024,5,19,6,2028
2024,5,19,7,1776
2024,5,19,8,1610
2024,5,19,9,1566
2024,5,19,10,1646
2024,5,19,11,1826
2024,5,19,12,2041
2024,5,19,13,2249
2024,5,19,14,2370
2024,5,19,15,2398
2024,5,19,16,2300
2024,5,19,17,2109
2024,5,19,18,1907
2024,5,19,19,1737
2024,5,19,20,1655
2024,5,19,21,1693
2024,5,19,22,1846
2024,5,19,23,2089
2024,5,20,0,2400
2024,5,20,1,2670
2024,5,20,2,2838
2024,5,20,3,2859
2024,5,20,4,2731
2024,5,20,5,2482
2024,5,20,6,2147
2024,5,20,7,1834
2024,5,20,8,1581
2024,5,20,9,1440
2024,5,20,10,1458
2024,5,20,11,1591
2024,5,20,12,1825
2024,5,20,13,2098
2024,5,20,14,2297
2024,5,20,15,2410
2024,5,20,16,2393
2024,5,20,17,2254
2024,5,20,18,2071
2024,5,20,19,1894
2024,5,20,20,1761
2024,5,20,21,1744
2024,5,20,22,1853
2024,5,20,23,2077
2024,5,21,0,2375
2024,5,21,1,2655
2024,5,21,2,2874
2024,5,21,3,2961
2024,5,21,4,2883
2024,5,21,5,2657
2024,5,21,6,2296
2024,5,21,7,1914
2024,5,21,8,1571
2024,5,21,9,1348
2024,5,21,10,1286
2024,5,21,11,1369
2024,5,21,12,1589
2024,5,21,13,1881
2024,5,21,14,2143
2024,5,21,15,2334
2024,5,21,16,2404
2024,5,21,17,2350
2024,5,21,18,2201
2024,5,21,19,2007
2024,5,21,20,1856
2024,5,21,21,1797
2024,5,21,22,1861
2024,5,21,23,2053
2024,5,22,0,2314
2024,5,22,1,2610
2024,5,22,2,2874
2024,5,22,3,3026
2024,5,22,4,3009
2024,5,22,5,2815
2024,5,22,6,2496
2024,5,22,7,2097
2024,5,22,8,1682
2024,5,22,9,1365
2024,5,22,10,1208
2024,5,22,11,1196
2024,5,22,12,1346
2024,5,22,13,1608
2024,5,22,14,1903
2024,5,22,15,2164
2024,5,22,16,2339
2024,5,22,17,2356
2024,5,22,18,2272
2024,5,22,19,2107
2024,5,22,20,1955
2024,5,22,21,1850
2024,5,22,22,1857
2024,5,22,23,1997
2024,5,23,0,2241
2024,5,23,1,2536
2024,5,23,2,2826
2024,5,23,3,3033
2024,5,23,4,3098
2024,5,23,5,2980
2024,5,23,6,2686
2024,5,23,7,2283
2024,5,23,8,1850
2024,5,23,9,1461
2024,5,23,10,1185
2024,5,23,11,1084
2024,5,23,12,1179
2024,5,23,13,1380
2024,5,23,14,1675
2024,5,23,15,1962
2024,5,23,16,2211
2024,5,23,17,2334
2024,5,23,18,2326
2024,5,23,19,2238
2024,5,23,20,2091
2024,5,23,21,1968
2024,5,23,22,1925
2024,5,23,23,1991
2024,5,24,0,2171
2024,5,24,1,2448
2024,5,24,2,2751
2024,5,24,3,2993
2024,5,24,4,3128
2024,5,24,5,3109
2024,5,24,6,2896
2024,5,24,7,2556
2024,5,24,8,2108
2024,5,24,9,1661
2024,5,24,10,1313
2024,5,24,11,1093
2024,5,24,12,1056
2024,5,24,13,1206
2024,5,24,14,1442
2024,5,24,15,1752
2024,5,24,16,2025
2024,5,24,17,2220
2024,5,24,18,2303
2024,5,24,19,2279
2024,5,24,20,2167
2024,5,24,21,2062
2024,5,24,22,1978
2024,5,24,23,1988
2024,5,25,0,2111
2024,5,25,1,2335
2024,5,25,2,2621
2024,5,25,3,2893
2024,5,25,4,3085
2024,5,25,5,3142
2024,5,25,6,3026
2024,5,25,7,2764
2024,5,25,8,2373
2024,5,25,9,1912
2024,5,25,10,1500
2024,5,25,11,1185
2024,5,25,12,1023
2024,5,25,13,1042
2024,5,25,14,1198
2024,5,25,15,1460
2024,5,25,16,1758
2024,5,25,17,2017
2024,5,25,18,2183
2024,5,25,19,2250
2024,5,25,20,2206
2024,5,25,21,2110
2024,5,25,22,2033
2024,5,25,23,2004
2024,5,26,0,2058
2024,5,26,1,2203
2024,5,26,2,2436
2024,5,26,3,2719
2024,5,26,4,2954
2024,5,26,5,3094
2024,5,26,6,3092
2024,5,26,7,2925
2024,5,26,8,2635
2024,5,26,9,2231
2024,5,26,10,1808
2024,5,26,11,1422
2024,5,26,12,1159
2024,5,26,13,1063
2024,5,26,14,1100
2024,5,26,15,1277
2024,5,26,16,1525
2024,5,26,17,1792
2024,5,26,18,2020
2024,5,26,19,2172
2024,5,26,20,2229
2024,5,26,21,2203
2024,5,26,22,2115
2024,5,26,23,2061
2024,5,27,0,2044
2024,5,27,1,2113
2024,5,27,2,2287
2024,5,27,3,2496
2024,5,27,4,2727
2024,5,27,5,2923
2024,5,27,6,3012
2024,5,27,7,2984
2024,5,27,8,2814
2024,5,27,9,2504
2024,5,27,10,2135
2024,5,27,11,1734
2024,5,27,12,1406
2024,5,27,13,1174
2024,5,27,14,1080
2024,5,27,15,1141
2024,5,27,16,1331
2024,5,27,17,1556
2024,5,27,18,1811
2024,5,27,19,2036
2024,5,27,20,2164
2024,5,27,21,2223
2024,5,27,22,2217
2024,5,27,23,2146
2024,5,28,0,2102
2024,5,28,1,2082
2024,5,28,2,2146
2024,5,28,3,2298
2024,5,28,4,2483
2024,5,28,5,2691
2024,5,28,6,2829
2024,5,28,7,2896
2024,5,28,8,2856
2024,5,28,9,2681
2024,5,28,10,2409
2024,5,28,11,2079
2024,5,28,12,1736
2024,5,28,13,1433
2024,5,28,14,1221
2024,5,28,15,1167
2024,5,28,16,1228
2024,5,28,17,1386
2024,5,28,18,1601
2024,5,28,19,1849
2024,5,28,20,2082
2024,5,28,21,2233
2024,5,28,22,2291
2024,5,28,23,2288
2024,5,29,0,2223
2024,5,29,1,2163
2024,5,29,2,2128
2024,5,29,3,2161
2024,5,29,4,2256
2024,5,29,5,2406
2024,5,29,6,2570
2024,5,29,7,2702
2024,5,29,8,2757
2024,5,29,9,2728
2024,5,29,10,2591
2024,5,29,11,2354
2024,5,29,12,2060
2024,5,29,13,1746
2024,5,29,14,1479
2024,5,29,15,1292
2024,5,29,16,1217
2024,5,29,17,1270
2024,5,29,18,1439
2024,5,29,19,1684
2024,5,29,20,1938
2024,5,29,21,2171
2024,5,29,22,2336
2024,5,29,23,2406
2024,5,30,0,2367
2024,5,30,1,2296
2024,5,30,2,2213
2024,5,30,3,2141
2024,5,30,4,2123
2024,5,30,5,2193
2024,5,30,6,2296
2024,5,30,7,2410
2024,5,30,8,2546
2024,5,30,9,2646
2024,5,30,10,2650
2024,5,30,11,2559
2024,5,30,12,2371
2024,5,30,13,2112
2024,5,30,14,1834
2024,5,30,15,1570
2024,5,30,16,1384
2024,5,30,17,1314
2024,5,30,18,1380
2024,5,30,19,1560
2024,5,30,20,1807
2024,5,30,21,2107
2024,5,30,22,2359
2024,5,30,23,2520
2024,5,31,0,2573
2024,5,31,1,2522
2024,5,31,2,2399
2024,5,31,3,2251
2024,5,31,4,2099
2024,5,31,5,2036
2024,5,31,6,2040
2024,5,31,7,2108
2024,5,31,8,2229
2024,5,31,9,2398
2024,5,31,10,2521
2024,5,31,11,2583
2024,5,31,12,2544
2024,5,31,13,2392
2024,5,31,14,2162
2024,5,31,15,1912
2024,5,31,16,1653
2024,5,31,17,1476
2024,5,31,18,1438
2024,5,31,19,1508
2024,5,31,20,1718
2024,5,31,21,2012
2024,5,31,22,2324
2024,5,31,23,2599

# year,month,day,hour,height
2024,4,30,0,12.399
2024,4,30,1,12.619
2024,4,30,2,12.264
2024,4,30,5,11.973
2024,4,30,7,11.324
2024,4,30,9,11.337
2024,4,30,10,12.18
2024,4,30,12,12.978
2024,4,30,13,12.868
2024,4,30,14,13.406
2024,4,30,15,13.462
2024,4,30,16,12.936
2024,4,30,17,13.339
2024,4,30,18,12.985
2024,4,30,22,12.016
2024,4,30,23,12.3
2024,5,1,0,11.731
2024,5,1,1,12.089
2024,5,1,3,11.733
2024,5,1,4,11.925
2024,5,1,5,12.003
2024,5,1,6,12.374
2024,5,1,8,12.467
2024,5,1,10,11.612
2024,5,1,11,11.63
2024,5,1,12,12.166
2024,5,1,13,12.741
2024,5,1,14,12.947
2024,5,1,15,13.449
2024,5,1,16,12.891
2024,5,1,17,12.875
2024,5,1,18,13.299
2024,5,1,20,12.732
2024,5,1,21,12.587
2024,5,1,22,12.2
2024,5,1,23,12.357
2024,5,2,0,11.846
2024,5,2,1,11.876
2024,5,2,2,12.133
2024,5,2,3,11.982
2024,5,2,4,12.121
2024,5,2,5,12.38
2024,5,2,6,12.633
2024,5,2,7,12.106
2024,5,2,8,12.075
2024,5,2,9,12.02
2024,5,2,10,11.681
2024,5,2,12,11.896
2024,5,2,13,11.952
2024,5,2,14,12.321
2024,5,2,15,12.681
2024,5,2,16,13.175
2024,5,2,17,13.123
2024,5,2,18,13.433
2024,5,2,19,12.871
2024,5,2,20,12.965
2024,5,2,21,12.734
2024,5,2,22,12.276
2024,5,2,23,11.888
2024,5,3,0,11.377
2024,5,3,1,11.706
2024,5,3,2,11.789
2024,5,3,3,11.937
2024,5,3,4,12.187
2024,5,3,5,12.572
2024,5,3,6,12.41
2024,5,3,7,12.426
2024,5,3,8,11.957
2024,5,3,9,12.048
2024,5,3,10,12.131
2024,5,3,11,11.741
2024,5,3,12,11.779
2024,5,3,13,11.354
2024,5,3,14,11.773
2024,5,3,15,12.512
2024,5,3,16,12.579
2024,5,3,18,13.339
2024,5,3,19,13.179
2024,5,3,20,12.773
2024,5,3,21,12.633
2024,5,3,22,12.382
2024,5,3,23,12.2
2024,5,4,0,11.607
2024,5,4,1,11.665
2024,5,4,2,11.735
2024,5,4,3,11.661
2024,5,4,4,12.19
2024,5,4,5,11.987
2024,5,4,6,12.689
2024,5,4,7,12.996
2024,5,4,8,12.936
2024,5,4,9,12.803
2024,5,4,10,12.112
2024,5,4,11,12.003
2024,5,4,12,11.639
2024,5,4,13,11.517
2024,5,4,14,11.631
2024,5,4,15,11.84
2024,5,4,16,12.147
2024,5,4,17,12.442
2024,5,4,18,13.051
2024,5,4,19,12.875
2024,5,4,21,12.935
2024,5,4,22,12.384
2024,5,4,23,12.141
2024,5,5,0,11.678
2024,5,5,1,11.653
2024,5,5,2,11.343
2024,5,5,3,11.11
2024,5,5,4,11.634
2024,5,5,5,11.987
2024,5,5,7,12.788
2024,5,5,9,12.801
2024,5,5,10,12.56
2024,5,5,11,12.121
2024,5,5,12,11.918
2024,5,5,13,11.83
2024,5,5,14,11.733
2024,5,5,16,12.061
2024,5,5,20,13.419
2024,5,6,0,11.69
2024,5,6,1,12.019
2024,5,6,3,11.155
2024,5,6,9,13.912
2024,5,6,10,13.562
2024,5,6,11,13.082
2024,5,6,12,12.992
2024,5,6,16,12.154
2024,5,6,17,12.227
2024,5,6,19,12.81
2024,5,6,21,12.468
2024,5,6,22,12.585
2024,5,7,0,11.661
2024,5,7,1,11.821
2024,5,7,2,11.235
2024,5,7,3,11.273
2024,5,7,4,11.353
2024,5,7,7,13.346
2024,5,7,9,13.249
2024,5,7,10,13.414
2024,5,7,11,13.653
2024,5,7,12,13.52
2024,5,7,14,12.492
2024,5,7,16,12.503
2024,5,7,18,12.902
2024,5,7,19,12.989
2024,5,7,20,12.82
2024,5,7,21,13.16
2024,5,7,22,12.674
2024,5,8,1,11.414
2024,5,8,2,11.289
2024,5,8,3,10.593
2024,5,8,4,11.204
2024,5,8,8,13.127
2024,5,8,10,13.899
2024,5,8,11,13.915
2024,5,8,13,13.366
2024,5,8,14,12.318
2024,5,8,16,11.922
2024,5,8,18,12.106
2024,5,9,0,12.445
2024,5,9,2,11.46
2024,5,9,4,11.371
2024,5,9,5,11.066
2024,5,9,7,11.485
2024,5,9,8,12.895
2024,5,9,10,13.269
2024,5,9,11,13.632
2024,5,9,12,13.644
2024,5,9,13,13.5
2024,5,9,14,13.18
2024,5,9,15,12.678
2024,5,9,16,12.448
2024,5,9,18,12.012
2024,5,9,19,12.029
2024,5,9,20,12.25
2024,5,9,21,12.347
2024,5,9,22,12.453
2024,5,10,0,12.309
2024,5,10,1,12.132
2024,5,10,2,11.754
2024,5,10,4,11.51
2024,5,10,5,11.258
2024,5,10,7,11.568
2024,5,10,8,12.344
2024,5,10,9,12.721
2024,5,10,10,12.864
2024,5,10,11,13.223
2024,5,10,12,13.451
2024,5,10,13,13.428
2024,5,10,14,13.166
2024,5,10,15,12.87
2024,5,10,16,12.626
2024,5,10,17,12.787
2024,5,10,18,12.254
2024,5,10,19,12.1
2024,5,10,20,12.087
2024,5,10,21,12.226
2024,5,10,22,12.301
2024,5,11,0,12.15
2024,5,11,1,12.108
2024,5,11,2,11.945
2024,5,11,3,11.524
2024,5,11,4,11.568
2024,5,11,5,11.144
2024,5,11,7,11.325
2024,5,11,8,11.663
2024,5,11,9,12.172
2024,5,11,10,12.469
2024,5,11,11,12.84
2024,5,11,12,12.891
2024,5,11,13,13.145
2024,5,11,14,13.337
2024,5,11,15,13.014
2024,5,11,16,12.71
2024,5,11,17,12.297
2024,5,11,18,12.454
2024,5,11,19,12.061
2024,5,11,20,12.08
2024,5,11,21,12.032
2024,5,11,22,12.16
2024,5,11,23,12.232
2024,5,12,0,12.179
2024,5,12,1,12.088
2024,5,12,2,11.981
2024,5,12,3,11.652
2024,5,12,4,11.584
2024,5,12,5,11.392
2024,5,12,7,11.364
2024,5,12,8,11.563
2024,5,12,9,12.002
2024,5,12,10,12.159
2024,5,12,11,12.505
2024,5,12,12,12.858
2024,5,12,14,13.177
2024,5,12,15,12.892
2024,5,12,16,12.849
2024,5,12,17,12.695
2024,5,12,18,12.576
2024,5,12,19,12.262
2024,5,12,20,12.102
2024,5,12,21,11.984
2024,5,12,22,11.987
2024,5,12,23,12.066
2024,5,13,0,12.146
2024,5,13,1,12.059
2024,5,13,2,12.129
2024,5,13,3,11.874
2024,5,13,4,11.842
2024,5,13,5,11.658
2024,5,13,7,11.475
2024,5,13,8,11.692
2024,5,13,9,11.791
2024,5,13,10,11.872
2024,5,13,11,12.094
2024,5,13,12,12.646
2024,5,13,14,12.99
2024,5,13,15,12.868
2024,5,13,16,12.993
2024,5,13,17,12.828
2024,5,13,18,12.751
2024,5,13,19,12.44
2024,5,13,20,12.3
2024,5,13,21,12.059
2024,5,13,22,11.977
2024,5,13,23,11.993
2024,5,14,0,12.043
2024,5,14,1,12.054
2024,5,14,2,12.163
2024,5,14,3,12.018
2024,5,14,4,11.972
2024,5,14,5,11.84
2024,5,14,6,11.732
2024,5,14,7,11.646
2024,5,14,8,11.76
2024,5,14,9,11.73
2024,5,14,10,11.735
2024,5,14,11,11.96
2024,5,14,12,12.263
2024,5,14,13,12.456
2024,5,14,14,12.731
2024,5,14,15,12.873
2024,5,14,16,12.874
2024,5,14,17,12.888
2024,5,14,19,12.58
2024,5,14,20,12.321
2024,5,14,21,12.153
2024,5,14,22,11.973
2024,5,14,23,11.96
2024,5,15,0,11.99
2024,5,15,1,11.907
2024,5,15,2,11.847
2024,5,15,3,12.02
2024,5,15,4,12.057
2024,5,15,5,12.016
2024,5,15,6,11.943
2024,5,15,7,11.914
2024,5,15,8,11.952
2024,5,15,9,11.828
2024,5,15,10,11.751
2024,5,15,11,11.792
2024,5,15,12,11.937
2024,5,15,13,12.22
2024,5,15,14,12.405
2024,5,15,15,12.561
2024,5,15,16,12.832
2024,5,15,17,12.814
2024,5,15,19,12.651
2024,5,15,20,12.535
2024,5,15,21,12.161
2024,5,15,22,12.139
2024,5,15,23,12.039
2024,5,16,0,11.906
2024,5,16,1,11.917
2024,5,16,2,11.72
2024,5,16,3,12.054
2024,5,16,4,12.256
2024,5,16,5,12.112
2024,5,16,6,12.039
2024,5,16,7,12.133
2024,5,16,8,12.178
2024,5,16,9,12.022
2024,5,16,10,11.77
2024,5,16,11,11.939
2024,5,16,12,11.844
2024,5,16,13,11.97
2024,5,16,14,12.259
2024,5,16,15,12.43
2024,5,16,16,12.56
2024,5,16,17,12.831
2024,5,16,18,12.843
2024,5,16,19,12.706
2024,5,16,20,12.651
2024,5,16,21,12.361
2024,5,16,22,12.263
2024,5,16,23,12.031
2024,5,17,0,11.894
2024,5,17,1,11.749
2024,5,17,2,11.729
2024,5,17,3,11.975
2024,5,17,4,12.024
2024,5,17,5,12.36
2024,5,17,6,12.358
2024,5,17,7,12.392
2024,5,17,8,12.531
2024,5,17,9,12.211
2024,5,17,10,12.179
2024,5,17,11,12.024
2024,5,17,12,11.884
2024,5,17,13,11.988
2024,5,17,14,12.148
2024,5,17,15,12.216
2024,5,17,16,12.404
2024,5,17,17,12.667
2024,5,17,18,12.818
2024,5,17,19,12.699
2024,5,17,20,12.732
2024,5,17,21,12.412
2024,5,17,22,12.212
2024,5,17,23,12.078
2024,5,18,0,11.866
2024,5,18,1,11.52
2024,5,18,2,11.583
2024,5,18,3,11.781
2024,5,18,4,11.795
2024,5,18,5,12.115
2024,5,18,6,12.426
2024,5,18,7,12.526
2024,5,18,8,12.444
2024,5,18,9,12.607
2024,5,18,10,12.36
2024,5,18,11,12.217
2024,5,18,12,11.956
2024,5,18,13,11.846
2024,5,18,14,11.883
2024,5,18,15,12.106
2024,5,18,16,12.264
2024,5,18,17,12.471
2024,5,18,18,12.745
2024,5,18,19,12.616
2024,5,18,20,12.71
2024,5,18,21,12.493
2024,5,18,22,12.363
2024,5,18,23,12.153
2024,5,19,1,11.611
2024,5,19,2,11.344
2024,5,19,3,11.994
2024,5,19,4,11.839
2024,5,19,5,12.186
2024,5,19,6,12.519
2024,5,19,7,12.741
2024,5,19,8,12.79
2024,5,19,9,12.71
2024,5,19,10,12.718
2024,5,19,11,12.351
2024,5,19,12,12.076
2024,5,19,13,11.938
2024,5,19,14,11.923
2024,5,19,15,11.921
2024,5,19,16,12.08
2024,5,19,17,12.497
2024,5,19,18,12.485
2024,5,19,19,12.657
2024,5,19,20,12.629
2024,5,19,21,12.589
2024,5,19,22,12.446
2024,5,19,23,12.273


You could measure dis/agreement with absolute difference - that's the easy part. Fitting one dataset to another really depends on the kinds of invariance you want to preserve, so I am unable to give a more helpful answer without additional informtion

I guess I'd say minimize the total difference between corresponding points over the entire range of data. I have defined a variable which is the difference between the two. What steps would I then take to minimize this variable?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please add your dataset as formatted code or shared link.

Just edited the post and added the csv datasets

Lets import your two dataset:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize

def read(file, keys=['year', 'month', 'day', "hour"]):
    frame = pd.read_csv(file)
    frame["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(frame[keys])
    frame = frame.drop(keys, axis=1).set_index("timestamp")
    return frame

ch1 = read("channel1.csv")
ch2 = read("channel2.csv")

Then, we align data, remove outliers and interpolate missing values:
data = ch1.merge(ch2, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=("_ref", "_exp"))
data[data < 0] = np.nan
data = data.resample("1h").interpolate()

Now we can check that your second sensor (exp) is anti correlated with your reference sensor (ref):
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.scatter(data["height_exp"], data["height_ref"])
axe.grid()


Therefore a simple linear model will do:
def model(x, a, b):
    return a * x + b

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, data["height_exp"], data["height_ref"])
# (array([ -773.39967406, 11645.38173753]),
#  array([[  320.87174002, -3943.48160713],
#         [-3943.48160713, 48563.90105644]]))

Now we regress the corrected sensor signal:
data["height_fit"] = model(data["height_exp"], *popt)

It leads to:
axe = data.plot()
axe.grid()


Which makes the second sensor linearly fit your reference.
